# Edit other user as admin, ruby on rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want, that a user with the admin role can edit other users from users/index.html.erb view. I'm not the first one asking this question, but all the given answers lack clear instructions.

So the problem is; after editing the fields, when I click on the 'Updtate' button in users/index.html.erb view, the page is reloaded but no changes appens.

Aditionnal infos: I'm using Devise and Omniauth facebook.

The users are display in the users/index via a partial:

```
  <td>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </td>

  <td>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.text_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </td>

  <td>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit I18n.translate('control.update'), class: 'btn sign-up-button' %>
    </div>
  </td>

  <td>
    <!-- display a delete button if the user is not the current_user -->
    <%= link_to(I18n.translate('control.delete'), user_path(user), :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure?" }, :method => :delete, :class => 'btn') unless user == current_user %>
  </td>
```

users/index.html.erb:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">

      <h2 class="text-center"><%= I18n.translate('user.users_list') %></h2>
      <div class="column">
        <table class="table">
          <tbody>
            <% @users.each do |user| %>
              <tr>
                <%= render user %>
              </tr>
            <% end %>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

      <ul class=”pagination”>
        <li><%= will_paginate(@users) %></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

My user_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :ensure_admin, :except => :show

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 8)
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find_by_name(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update(secure_params)
      redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User updated."
    else
      redirect_to users_path, :alert => "Unable to update user."
    end
  end

  def destroy
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    user.destroy
    redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User deleted."
  end

  private

  def ensure_admin
    if(current_user.role == 'admin')
      return
    end
    redirect_to root_path, :alert => "Access denied."
  end

  def secure_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:role)
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :name, :password)
  end
end
```

My routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'pages#index'

  get 'users/index'

  # you can type '/users' to view the users
  match '/users', to: 'users#index', via: 'get'

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations",
                                      :path_prefix => 'd',
                                      :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }

  resources :users

  scope '/:locale' do
    devise_scope :user do
      get 'login', to: 'devise/sessions#new'
    end
    devise_scope :user do
      get 'signup', to: 'devise/registrations#new'
    end
end
```

Comment: Please add the form declaration (`<%= simple_form_for […] %>`) and the logs after submit, that will be useful to help you

Comment: you are using the wrong params on updating the user. I think you meant to use the user_params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in the user_controller update action you are calling secure_params def, which is permitting only "role" field.

I think you should to use user_params in update action like below

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update(user_params)
    redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User updated."
  else
    redirect_to users_path, :alert => "Unable to update user."
  end
end
```

Or you will have to permit other params also in secure_params def like

```
def secure_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:role,:name,:email)
end
```

Hope it would help you.